# No data filled in the newly created excel file after usint the .to_excel function (pandas)

Tags: pandas

from pathlib import Path  # Core Python Module
import pandas as pd  # pip install pandas openpyxl
import xlwings as xw  # pip install xlwings

df1 = pd.read_excel('italy.xlsx')
df_it = pd.DataFrame(df1, columns=['asini'])

df2 = pd.read_excel('spain.xlsx')
df_es = pd.DataFrame(df2, columns=['asini'])

compare = df_it.compare(df_es, align_axis=1, keep_shape=True, keep_equal=False)

compare.to_excel('multiple.xlsx')

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

pd.read_excel() will move the data from the file to a dataframe. So, you should not be using pd.DataFrame() again. As data is not provided, I am not sure of the other steps. But, you need to do this to read the data and update the column names. Hope this is what you are looking for...

```
df_it = pd.read_excel('italy.xlsx') 
df_it.set_axis(['asini'], axis='columns', inplace = True) #Rename the one column DF to asini

df_es = pd.read_excel('spain.xlsx') 
df_es.set_axis(['asini'], axis='columns', inplace = True) #Rename the one column DF to asini
```